# What's the name of this function, ()_+,? Take positive parts?

Tags: vectors

The notation I am asking came from Soft Thresholding, section 4.4.3 of [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) (page 32)

$
S_{\kappa}(a) = (1-\frac{\kappa}{|a|})_{+}a
$

I would like to know the name of $()_+$ function to study further. I know a is a matrix and $\kappa$ is scalar and the division is a piecewise operation. The book doesn't explain much. I appreciate any kind of hint!

**Suggested Solution:**

I think $(a)_+$ means, taking nonnegative parts of a such that

$
(a_i)_+ =
$
$
\begin{cases}
max(a_i,0)          &    & a_i>0 \\
0                   &    & otherwise
\end{cases}
$

$
i = 1, 2, 3 ...
$

Can someone please confirm?

Comment: In engineering these are called Macauley brackets: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay_brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the [positive part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts). You can check with cases that, provided $\kappa\ge0$, it agrees with the definition two lines above:

$$S_k(a)=\begin{cases}a-\kappa&\text{if }a>\kappa\\ 0&\text{if }\lvert a\rvert\le k\\ a+\kappa&\text{if }a<-\kappa\end{cases}$$

**Added:**
While it's still there and it's still 1st April, let us all appreciate this *big brain* excerpt from the wikipedia page I have linked:

> If we combine [$f^+$ and $f^-$] together, we can (we'll) make
> $$f^{\pm}=\operatorname{med}(f(x),0)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }f(x)=0\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$